# aggregate subset returning this error: NAs introduced by coercion

Tags: r, aggregate-functions

I'm having trouble finding the mean for a subset of data. Here are the two questions I'm hoping to answer. The first seems to be working fine, but the second returns the same answer as the first, but without numbers to the right of the decimal place. What's going on?

There is also an error that appears: 
NAs introduced by coercionNAs introduced by coercionNAs introduced by coercionNAs introduced by coercion

```
# What is the mean suspension rate for schools by farms overall?
aggregate(suspension_rate_total ~  farms, merged_data, FUN = function(suspension_rate_total)
  mean(as.numeric(as.character(suspension_rate_total))))

# What is the mean suspension rate for schools with farms > 100? 
aggregate(suspension_rate_total ~  farms, merged_data, FUN = function(suspension_rate_total)
  mean(as.numeric(as.character(suspension_rate_total))), subset = farms< 100)
```

**Data**

```
merged_data <- structure(list(schid = c("1030642", "1030766", "1030774", "1030840", 
"1130103", "1230150", "1530435", "1530492", "1530500", "1931047", 
"1931708", "1931864", "1932623", "1933746", "1937226", "1938554", 
"1938612", "1938885", "1995836", "1996016"), farms = c("132", 
"116", "348", "406", "68", "130", "370", "204", "225", "2,616", 
"1,106", "1,918", "1,148", "2,445", "1,123", "1,245", "1,369", 
"1,073", "932", "178"), foster = c("2", "0", "1", "8", "1", "4", 
"4", "0", "0", "22", "11", "12", "2", "8", "13", "13", "4", "3", 
"2", "3"), homeless = c("14", "0", "8", "4", "1", "4", "5", "0", 
"14", "35", "42", "116", "9", "8", "34", "54", "26", "31", "5", 
"11"), migrant = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "18", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0"), ell = c("18", 
"12", "114", "45", "7", "4", "50", "28", "26", "274", "212", 
"325", "95", "112", "232", "185", "121", "84", "24", "35"), suspension_rate_total = c("*", 
"20", "0", "0", "95", "5", "*", "256", "78", "33", "20", "1", 
"218", "120", "0", "0", "*", "*", "*", "0"), suspension_violent = c("*", 
"9", "0", "0", "20", "2", "*", "38", "0", "6", "3", "0", "53", 
"35", "0", "0", "*", "*", "*", "0"), suspension_violent_no_injury = c("*", 
"6", "0", "0", "47", "1", "*", "121", "52", "7", "13", "1", "77", 
"44", "0", "0", "*", "*", "*", "0"), suspension_weapon = c("*", 
"0", "0", "0", "8", "0", "*", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "4", "3", 
"0", "0", "*", "*", "*", "0"), suspension_drug = c("*", "0", 
"0", "0", "9", "1", "*", "59", "12", "16", "0", "0", "6", "5", 
"0", "0", "*", "*", "*", "0"), suspension_defiance = c("*", "1", 
"0", "0", "9", "1", "*", "16", "12", "0", "3", "0", "69", "30", 
"0", "0", "*", "*", "*", "0"), suspension_other = c("*", "4", 
"0", "0", "2", "0", "*", "21", "2", "3", "0", "0", "9", "3", 
"0", "0", "*", "*", "*", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you so much.

**Image-1**
[image: image1]

**Image-2**
[image: image2]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210565/discussion-on-question-by-claire-123-aggregate-subset-returning-this-error-nas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tidy up your data:**

```
# replace * with NA
merged_data$suspension_rate_total[merged_data$suspension_rate_total == '*'] <- NA
# convert character to numeric format
merged_data$suspension_rate_total <- as.numeric(merged_data$suspension_rate_total)
# remove comma in strings and convert character to numeric format
merged_data$farms <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", merged_data$farms))
```

**Output**

```
# What is the mean suspension rate for schools by farms overall?
aggregate(suspension_rate_total ~  farms, merged_data, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)

#    farms suspension_rate_total
# 1     68                    95
# 2    116                    20
# 3    130                     5
# 4    178                     0
# 5    204                   256
# 6    225                    78
# 7    348                     0
# 8    406                     0
# 9   1106                    20
# 10  1123                     0
# 11  1148                   218
# 12  1245                     0
# 13  1918                     1
# 14  2445                   120
# 15  2616                    33

# What is the mean suspension rate for schools with farms > 100? 
aggregate(suspension_rate_total ~  farms, merged_data, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE, subset = farms > 100)

# farms suspension_rate_total
# 1    116                    20
# 2    130                     5
# 3    178                     0
# 4    204                   256
# 5    225                    78
# 6    348                     0
# 7    406                     0
# 8   1106                    20
# 9   1123                     0
# 10  1148                   218
# 11  1245                     0
# 12  1918                     1
# 13  2445                   120
# 14  2616                    33
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure 'NA's introduced by coercion' is a error and not a warning.
When you convert a character column to numeric : 
 `as.numeric(as.character(suspension_rate_total))` , the blanks are coerced into NA's , which is intimated through warnings.

Also, I get different answers for both blocks of code

```
> aggregate(suspension_rate_total ~  farms, merged_data, FUN = function(suspension_rate_total)
+   mean(as.numeric(as.character(suspension_rate_total))))
   farms suspension_rate_total
1     68                    95
2    116                    20
3    130                     5
4    132                    NA
5    178                     0
6    204                   256
7    225                    78
8    348                     0
9    370                    NA
10   406                     0
11   932                    NA
```

```
> aggregate(suspension_rate_total ~  farms, merged_data, FUN = function(suspension_rate_total)
+     mean(as.numeric(as.character(suspension_rate_total))), subset = farms< 100)
  farms suspension_rate_total
1    68                    95
> 
>
```

Further, the comment on you second block of code mention `farms > 100?` , but in you code you used `subset = farms< 100`

Comment: Thanks Shubham! I added two images of the output I'm seeing with the full dataset when I put in the two strings of code. It looks like the create the same output, but with .0000 or not.